# How to test javascripts with selenium-webdriver/capybara/rspec/rails 4?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, selenium, rspec, capybara

I have a problem using selenium-webdriver/capybara/rspec/rails 4. (and cloud9)
I received the error below:

```
$ rspec spec/features/user_login_spec.rb 

  An error occurred in an after hook
    Net::ReadTimeout: Net::ReadTimeout
    occurred at /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/protocol.rb:158:in `rescue in rbuf_fill'


  An error occurred in an after hook
    Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError: chrome not reachable
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.15.322448 (52179c1b310fec1797c81ea9a20326839860b7d3),platform=Linux 3.14.13-c9 x86_64)
occurred at /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.45.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:52:in `assert_ok'

F
```

This is my gemfile.

```
group :test do
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'capybara-screenshot'
  gem "factory_girl_rails", "~> 4.0"
end
...
group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.0'
  gem "chromedriver-helper", "0.0.6"
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
end
```

This is spec/support/capybara.rb

```
require 'capybara/rails'
require 'capybara/rspec'

# By default Capybara will use Selenium+Firefox for `js:true` feature specs.
# Only if you're not using Puffing Billy, to use Chrome instead of Firefox,
# uncomment the following 3 lines:
Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :chrome)
end
```

This is spec/features/user_login_spec.rb

```
describe "User logs in", :type => :feature, js: true do
  before :each do
..
```

I recived no error when I delete `js: true` in `user_login_spec.rb`.